# How to convert a column of nvarchar string in hh:mm:ss format into datatype of time permanently in a table?

Tags: sql-server, string, time, nvarchar

I want to convert a table column like

Departure_time

06:44:00        (<- these are just **NVARCHAR** strings)

06:45:00

06:45:00

06:46:00

06:47:00

06:47:00

06:48:00

06:49:00

06:50:00

06:50:00

06:50:00

06:51:00

06:51:00

06:52:00

06:52:00

(sorry guys I really do want to post a screen-shot here which would made the post looks way much better but it says I need a reputation of 10. So, I just make one table column)

which in **NVARCHAR** datatype, into **TIME** type in MSSQL 2012?

I tried Time(0) and Time(7) and all threw an error of

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

and I do want to change the type of that column of the table permanently. Not only select them and present them in the time format.

So... anyone can help me on how to do this please?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to make a permanent conversion to the table's column, or are you wanting to change it when `SELECT`ing the data out? If you could include one of your attempts in your question, it could be useful - also, we tend to *prefer* text to screenshots - it's pretty difficult to copy and paste a screenshot into management studio and try it out ourselves, and we don't enjoy the typing practice transcribing from an image - much better to post text (or better yet, SQL scripts) that allow us to easily see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Ya I do want to permanent change it. I will edit the question content to make more clear! thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works as (I) would expect and ends up with a table consisting of a single `time(7)` column:

```
create table T (Departure_time nvarchar(10) not null)
insert into T(Departure_time) values
('06:44:00'),('06:45:00'),('06:45:00'),('06:46:00'),('06:47:00'),
('06:47:00'),('06:48:00'),('06:49:00'),('06:50:00'),('06:50:00'),
('06:50:00'),('06:51:00'),('06:51:00'),('06:52:00'),('06:52:00')

alter table T alter column Departure_Time time(7) not null
```

I suspect you have some rows which *don't* have valid values in them. These may be more or less easy to discover, depending on how close to the required format the invalid values are.

```
select * from t where not Departure_time like '[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
```

Finds values that are definitely wrong. But it wouldn't find e.g. `27:34:32`

Comment: Thanks Damien! Yes there are lots of rows have null value and others. there are about 2 million rows of data in that table so thanks you for helping me find them out. So is there any way that I can skip(or set some default value) at those values when I converting them?

Comment: @Ohhell... - you'll need to do the clean up first, as a separate step. `NULL`s shouldn't be an issue (provided you don't specify `NOT NULL` as part of the `ALTER` as I did above). You could always change me last query above to be an `UPDATE` that `SET`s the column to `NULL` before attempting the `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Ok and I just got a bunch of 25:xx:xx 27:xx:xx out of my table and it seems that the table creator did that in a purpose. So I would keep them in string format. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar(32),getdate(),8)
```

OR

```
DECLARE @DateNow smalldatetime
SET @DateNow = GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), @DateNow, 8)
```

OR

```
 UPDATE your_tablename
    SET columnName = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, columnName,105))
    ALTER TABLE myTable
    ALTER COLUMN columnName SMALLDATETIME
```

Comment: can you be more specific please? My table name is "stop_times" and that column is "departure_time" so where should I put those names? `select departure_time    from stop_times    convert(varchar(32),getdate(),8)` ?

Comment: UPDATE stop_time
    SET departure_time = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, departure_time,105)

Comment: I excuted and it gave me an error of "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." My data is all in the format of "hh:mm:ss". Any idea what it means?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I checked the data in the table again and find the data in the table do have error. So is there anything I can do to skip them or ignore them?

Comment: you could filter the duplicates from table

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple:

```
select cast (Departure_time as time) from <you_table>
```

Comment: I actually want to change the type of that column in the table, not only selecting them and view. Any suggestions?

Comment: In case when the previous query returns no errors, the most simple way to do this is to add another column with each name you want but with needed type, transfer data with the above query into it, remove the old column and rename the new one into the old name.